# Skipping the first n lines when using regex with sed?

Tags: unix, text, command-line, sed

In `sed`, is it possible to skip the first n lines when applying a regex? I am currently using the following:

```
cat test | sed '/^Name/d;/^----------/1;/^(/d;/^$/d'
```

on the following file:

```
Name
John
Albert
Mora
Name
Tommy
Tammy
```

In one pass, I want to use some regexes (one of which is to remove the line containing `Name` but I want to skip the first line in this case) to obtain the following:

```
Name
John
Albert
Mora
Tommy
Tammy
```

Because the file is huge, I don't want to make multiple passes so any one-pass approaches would be great.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, you can apply sed commands to ranges of lines with the `N,M` syntax. In this case you want something like this:

```
sed -e '2,$s/foo/bar/'
```

---

An example with delete:

```
sed -e '2,${ /^Name/d }'
```

Comment: Could you please show me how to use the syntax with delete as opposed to substitute? Basically, when I do something like this: `sed '2,$/^Name/d'` the command fails with the error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `/'`

Comment: +1 Just figured it out :) Thank you for pointing me the right direction.

Comment: '2,$' means from line 2 until the end of the file.
the item directly after $ is an operation. For these examples, either `s/search/replace` or `{ /^string-to-delete/d }`

Comment: Hm. I try `sed -e '2,${ /^Name/d }'` in Mac OS and it blows up with ```sed: 1: "2,${ /^Name/d }
": extra characters at the end of d command```