# Convert 'u' to 't' without changing headers in a FASTA

Tags: awk, sed, fasta

I am trying to figure out how to turn my mixed DNA/RNA multifasta

```
>header1
atcggtc
atgcgca
>useful header2
aucggca
uucacuu
ucucuca
>header3
agucuau
cuagggc
...
```

into DNA-only format without destroying the headers. My knowledge ends at

```
sed 's/u/t/g'
```

But this quite obviously affects the headers. Is there a way to avoid changing headers with sed or should I use another command? What should I look for?

Comment: Do you mean you want to skip the first line in a file?

Comment: It means I'd like to skip every header line, it's a multifasta, but yes that's the right direction : )

Comment: You should add some sample data so that others can answer properly.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869449/skipping-the-first-n-lines-when-using-regex-with-sed

Comment: `awk '/^>/{print; next}{gsub("u","t")}1' file.fasta`

Comment: @thilinajayanath I will edit now!

Comment: how does the header looks like, few lines of sample will help.

Comment: Don't assume that the people willing to help you know what `DNA-only format` or `the headers` means. [edit] your question to tell us how to identify a "header" and show the expected output given your posted sample input to remove any chance of confusion or misunderstanding.

Answer (score 8):

With `sed`, it's easy to say "do this only on selected lines". The general syntax is *address* *command* where *address* can be a regex to only match lines whose first character is not `>`.

```
sed '/^[^>]/s/u/t/g' file.fasta >newfile.fasta
```

The first `^` means beginning of line; the character class `[^>]` matches a single character which is not (newline or) `>`.

Awk is probably easier to learn, easier to read, and easier to remember going forward. The same script in Awk could look like

```
awk '/^[^>]/{ gsub(/u/,"t") }1' file.fasta >newfile.fasta
```

That last `1` is not a typo; it's an Awk idiom for "print all lines".

Comment: @EnricoMariadeAngelis I rolled back your edit as somewhat invasive. I'm fine with linking to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63891/19240 in a comment.

Comment: An alternative for sed might be: `sed '/^>/!y/u/t/' file`